# What's the meaning of "And this because"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of "And this because" in the [following text](http://www.indepthnews.info/index.php/global-issues/1860-challenges-remain-but-good-news-for-nuclear-disarmament)?

> *And this because*, Terasaki added, “there is both a practical and moral
>   imperative to rid the world of those apocalyptic weapons."

Answer (score 2):

It’s an instance of ellipsis. The reader has to supply the verb *is* after *this* (which refers to Terasaki’s preceding statement) to complete the sentence. This is not carelessness or an error, but a stylistic device. Whether or not it is effective is for each reader to judge.